# Root Query Create and Delete in Relay.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am trying to figure out how to create and delete nodes with Relay where I don't have a parent node. It seems that `NODE_DELETE`/`RANGE_DELETE` and `RANGE_ADD` all require a parent node. Is there a way to perform create and delete mutations from the root query object in Relay.js?

***Note:*** I did find example where creates can be performed with a FIELDS_CHANGE query, but they lack any documentation or reason.

Comment: What does this question have to do with React.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` for this purpose. It's not currently well-documented (or even documented), and it has a somewhat confusing name (as a result, [we have a task](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/237) for renaming it and improving the docs). It will likely be renamed to `EXTRA_FRAGMENT` in the future.

Normally when you issue a mutation, we perform an intersection between the "fat query" (all the fields that could possibly change as the result of the mutation) and the "tracked query" (all the fields that your app has requested for a node so far, and which should be updated when they change) and we send this query to the server with the mutation.

So, for the use case of creating an entirely new node with no parent, you can specify an identifying field like `id` in the `REQUIRED_CHILDREN`, and then use that to, for example, navigate to a view showing the newly-created object. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546415/2103996) has a very detailed example of how you would do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `client:root` as the `parentID`. And then your `pathToConnection` would be `['client:root', 'someConnection']`.

(Tested with Relay Modern. Not sure if this also applies to Relay Classic, but that's officially deprecated now anyways. But this is still one of the top Google results for this issue, so answering.)

(Found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1991))