# How do I add a Root Node

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

Adding a nested item is easy: the config is just a `RANGE_ADD`

```
query {
  viewer {
    item {
      edges {
        node {
          subitem {
            edges {
              node {
                id,
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding a `subitem` will just require a `RANGE_ADD` with the parentId equal to the id of `item`.

However, how do I add an `item` which doesn't have a parent? I tried using a `RANGE_ADD` config without a parentId but it didn't work.

I feel like this is such a simple thing, but I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` does have a parent, which is `viewer`. It's just that `viewer` can have one `item` instead of multiple `item`s as `item` is not a connection type. So when you want to add another `item`, you want to either:

1) replace / update the existing `item`. FIELDS_CHANGE is usually used in this case.

OR

2) fetch an `item` which does not need to be put in the client store. In this case, you can use [REQUIRED_CHILDREN](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html) mutator configuration. Check an excellent example of how to use it in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546415/2821632) to another related question.

Comment: The second one looks exactly like what I need. I don't have an existing item (creating a new one) so I can't use FIELDS_CHANGE

Comment: If you don't have an existing `item` under `viewer` and your mutation creates that `item`, you should update `viewer` and use `FIELDS_CHANGE`. The second one is not suitable for your use-case because it will not update the client store with the newly created `item`.